# irreducibility of exterior powers

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Suppose I have a subgroup $H$ of $GL(V)$ such that $H$ acts irreducibly on all the exterior powers of $V$. Is there any sort of characterization of such things? (I am intentionally not specifying the coefficients, since the results are presumably depend on these).

Comment: Do you mean such that H acts irreducibly on all exterior powers of V?

Comment: @NoahSnyder Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32401

Comment: An example is $S^n$ acting on $n$-tuples of numbers that sum to $0$, over any characteristic zero field.

Comment: @Igor: For an arbitrary subgroup $H$ I'm skeptical about finding a decent characterization, but maybe it's reasonable for more restrictive classes of groups.  Certainly there are problems with some of the classical linear groups, but not others; so a characterization would have to be rather subtle even over a field of characteristic 0.